# Trying to Set CLI path for mTurk for Mac

Tags: terminal, osx-yosemite, mechanicalturk

I am setting up the CLI on a MAC (iOS 10.9) and I believe I've set up the MTURK_CMD_HOME and JAVA_CMD_HOME paths correctly.

But, I'm still getting an error that the file can't be found when I run getBalance.sh. My code is as follows:

```
/users/USER/Desktop/aws-mturk-clt-1.3.1/
-bash: /users/USER/Desktop/aws-mturk-clt-1.3.1/: is a directory
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home
-bash: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home: is a directory
export MTURK_CMD_HOME=/users/USER/Desktop/aws-mturk-clt-1.3.1/
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home
export PATH=$PATH:/users/USER/Desktop/aws-mturk-clt-1.3.1/bin
/users/USER/Desktop/aws-mturk-clt-1.3.1/bin/getBalance.sh
```

Returns the following error:

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../log/aws-mturk-clt.log (No such file or      directory)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:192)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:116)
at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:290)
at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:194)
at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:164)
at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:257)
at        org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:133)
at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:97)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:689)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:647)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:544)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:440)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:476)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:471)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:125)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:118)
at com.amazonaws.mturk.cmd.AbstractCmd.<clinit>(AbstractCmd.java:51)
There was a problem reading your properties file from mturk.properties
The exception was java.io.FileNotFoundException: mturk.properties (No such     file or directory)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load     onfiguration properties file from mturk.properties
at com.amazonaws.mturk.util.PropertiesClientConfig.<init>    (PropertiesClientConfig.java:99)
at com.amazonaws.mturk.util.PropertiesClientConfig.<init>(PropertiesClientConfig.java:72)
at com.amazonaws.mturk.cmd.AbstractCmd.<init>(AbstractCmd.java:61)
at com.amazonaws.mturk.cmd.GetBalance.<init>(GetBalance.java:24)
at com.amazonaws.mturk.cmd.GetBalance.main(GetBalance.java:27)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: mturk.properties (No such file or     directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
at com.amazonaws.mturk.util.PropertiesClientConfig.<init>            (PropertiesClientConfig.java:95)
... 4 more
```

It seems the directory is specified correctly (and bin contains getBalance.sh). I've double checked that my access keys are correct and the file path is correct. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Set your directory:

```
cd /users/USER/Desktop/aws-mturk-clt-1.3.1/bin/
```

and then run `./getBalance.sh`